# How do I upload files from NextJS directly from browser to Cloud Storage or FTP server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

How do I upload files from `NextJS` directly from browser to `Cloud Storage` or `FTP server`?

I need to upload some files `directly from the browser to storage server`, do you think I can run something like `node-ftp` in the `api` routes of `Nextjs`? something like this:

```
// Upload local file 'foo.txt' to the ftp server
  var Client = require('ftp');
  var fs = require('fs');

  var c = new Client();
  c.on('ready', function() {
    c.put('foo.txt', 'foo.remote-copy.txt', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      c.end();
    });
  });
  // connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
  c.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced exactly the same battle - hopefully this isn't too late with a response for you but either way I guess this could be useful for the next guy. I'm not saying this is 100% the best way to do it - it's just the first method I found. I've stripped away some security features that I had as part of this to show just the working example. A real production version of this would require additional thought.

So the key to uploading from Next.JS to a FTP is that you want to send your content in a stream.

1. You'll need a form with a submit method that looks something like this

```
  const handleUpload = async (file: File) => {
    try {
      if (!file) return;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("myImage", file);
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/ftp/file-upload", formData);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.response?.data);
    }
  };
```

2. Then create a handler method in your api/ftp/file-upload

```
const handler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const response = await readFile(req, true);

  let realPath: string;
  if (Array.isArray(response.files.myImage)) {
    if (response.files.myImage.length > 0) {
      realPath = response.files.myImage[0].filepath;
    } else {
      realPath = "";
    }
  } else {
    realPath = response.files.myImage.filepath;
  }
 
  await uploadToFTP(realPath)
  await stampProfilePictureInDatabase( '/path/', fileName);

  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({});
};
```

There's a couple of key bits of information you want from this, the path the image is stored at locally to the user (or realPath as I call it). And then a friendly reminder that you'll most likely want to log all your file activity, so make sure you upload details to the database (included file location/size/name ect) so you can retrieve it at a later date if needs be.

```
import { Client } from 'basic-ftp';

const uploadToFTP = async (realPath: string) => {
  const client = new Client();
  client.ftp.verbose = true;

  try {
    await client.access({
      host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
      user: process.env.FTP_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
      port: parseInt(process.env.FTP_PORT + ''),
      secure: true,
      secureOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
    });

    await client.ensureDir("/path");

    const remotePath = '/path/' + fileName;

    await client.uploadFrom(realPath, remotePath);

    console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

So in short you can pretty much:

1. Check that the folder is a thing (and that you can access it)
2. Generate the path where you would want to put the file
3. Upload the file using the realPath into the remotePath.
4. Check on the FTP that the file is a thing, if you find your logging get's too busy feel free to remove `client.ftp.verbose = true;` - I just add this so that I know exactly what's going on.

Hopefully that has helped. Unfortunately I don't have a reference or anything, just me playing around with Next.JS. Have fun!